# Long conditional branches in Thumb-2

Tags: arm, thumb

Section A6.7.12 of the [ARMv7-M reference manual](https://silver.arm.com/download/download.tm?pv=1874087) gives four possible encodings for a branch instruction (`B`):

- T1: 16-bit instruction, 4-bit condition, 8-bit address
- T2: 16-bit instruction, no condition, 11-bit address
- T3: 32-bit instruction, 4-bit condition, 17-bit address
- T4: 32-bit instruction, no condition, 21-bit address

With T3 (and T1 and T2) I can only branch to address between -1048576 and 1048574 positions from the program counter. What should I do if I want a conditional branch to further away?

The following (in UAL):

```
it     ne
bne.w  some_far_label
```

gives me a deprecation warning:

```
Warning: IT blocks containing 32-bit Thumb instructions are deprecated in ARMv8
```

Comment: v7-M and v8-A (where that deprecation applies) are very different things - which one is actually relevant here?

Comment: @Notlikethat I'm working on a `ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)` (Raspberry Pi 2B), but want to generate Thumb-only code. I am actually generating this code, and want it to be applicable for processors that only have Thumb (like the Cortex M series) as well.

Comment: In which case you shouldn't be targeting ARMv8 at all. FWIW though, the best thing to do is simply disable that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do if I want a conditional branch to further away?

Just use the `MOV{cond} PC, Rx` instruction with the destination address in that register:

```
LDR R1, =some_very_far_label
IT NE
MOVNE PC, R1
```

Comment: Alright, I could have thought of that myself. Thanks though :) Qua efficiency, would putting the load in a conditional block as well be an improvement?

Comment: Yes, you could put the LDR into the IT block as a minor improvement.

Comment: I didn't mean to put it into the block, because ARMv8-A deprecates multiple instructions in an IT block, but to add an extra IT block. Anyway, I'll do a performance test myself. I'm away from my computer now but will try this out in a few hours and then probably upvote and accept this answer :)

Comment: `bxne r1` would arguably be better.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it the canonical 'unlimited branch' is simply `ldrne pc, =label` - Thumb literal loads still fall foul of the stupid ARMv8 deprecation thing, but then so does `mov` when Rd is the PC as here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about actually targeting ARMv7, the best thing to do about that warning is to simply ignore or disable it, ideally by not targeting ARMv8-A to provoke it in the first place.

For v7 CPUs it's utterly irrelevant; for existing v8-A CPUs, it's largely irrelevant as well, because the main point of AArch32 there is backwards compatibility with existing v7 code, and if they didn't run that code at least as well as their v7 predecessors, they wouldn't have been very popular. For future v8-A CPUs, once a significant proportion of software has transitioned to AArch64, there *might* potentially be some point in restructuring your AArch32 code to avoid IT blocks wherever possible, but either way, the very worst thing to do is to just end up with multiple back-to-back single-instruction blocks.

The whole thing is a bit silly, really. What the ARMv8-A Architecture Reference Manual says about the "Partial deprecation of IT" is:

> ARMv8-A deprecates some uses of the T32 `IT` instruction, for performance reasons. [...] The full ARMv7 `IT` instruction functionality remains available in order to execute legacy T32 code. [...]

Yes, there can be an optional control bit to trap the 'deprecated' uses, but even if a v8-A CPU does implement that, no OS which expects to run v7 code is ever going to set it. Multi-instruction IT blocks still have to be supported by future AArch32 implementations, they just might be slower than alternative code, so ARM tries to convince us to avoid them. Frankly, though, I'd imagine the theoretical future v8-A CPUs which aren't targeted at running existing 32-bit code, so might make optimisations which make it undesirably hard to support multi-instruction IT blocks efficiently, are probably more likely to just drop AArch32 support altogether anyway.

Comment: I really want this code generator to be as widely applicable as possible, hence my targeting v8-A even though I'm on a raspberry pi. However, thank you very much for the extensive explanation, it has certainly cleared up some things for me.